# Retain a javascript link when the context menu is used

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following link that opens a page in a new tab (in most browsers subject to the users configuration) provided that javascript is enabled and some conditions are met.

```
<a href="../scripts/no-javascript.htm" target="nojs" onclick="openWin(url,name); return false;">
```

href="../scripts/no-javascript.htm" is included for users who don’t have javascript enabled or where the conditions are not met (no-javascript.htm explains why). This can’t have the same url or name as the ones included with openWin(url,name).

Everything works fine except that if the user right clicks and selects “Open link in new tab/window” from the context menu they get taken to no-javascript.htm.

Is there any way I can have this format and still have the user go to openWin(url,name) when they use the context menu?

Thanks.

Comment: You could write a js redirect in the new page. I don't know other solutions. Maybe someone else can help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. (I'm assuming jquery here)

```
<a id='nojs' href="../scripts/no-javascript.htm" target="nojs" onclick="openWin(url,name); return false;">
<script>
if (!conditionsmet) {
    $("#nojs").attr("href", "http://something.else");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, how do you do that with javascript, I haven't used jquery as yet?

Comment: Sorry, too late reading this - but the other answer gives the non-jquery way.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use onClick. Just change the link with JS and if the user disables it you get the nojs page.

**HTML**

```
<a id="the-link" href="../scripts/no-javascript.htm" target="nojs">
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("the-link").href = "../new_link.htm";
```

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/43vnK/)**

Comment: thanks Itay Gal, I got what I needed from a combination of yours and the answer Chris gave. I can't mark them both as the answer so I marked yours as 'useful'. Hope that's okay.